# How to replace some path in a conf file using Vim?

Tags: vim

I have this

```
88 ca ca.crt
89 cert client.crt
90 key client.key
```

in openvpn's client.conf(the number is line num display by vim,not the actual text),and I would like to change ca.crt clent.crt client.key to the right palce which all lie in './easy-rsa/2.0/keys/'

I tried this way:

```
88,90s;^(\w) (\w);\1 easy-rsa/2.0/keys\2;
```

and it turned out to be 'pattern not found'

## [Solved]

I solved the problem using this:

```
:88,90s;\(^\w\+\>\)\s\(\w\+\>\);\1 easy-rsa/2.0/keys/\2;
```

the mistake I commit in the question is :
1. reference must be escape in the pattern so it should be `\( \)` not just `()`

Some explanation about the solution:
 `\w` just match a character that can form a word,so use the vim extended regex `\+` to match one or more `\w` and `\>` to imply the end of a word

and a simplier solution:

```
88,90s;\s\(\w*\); easy-rsa/2.0/keys/;
```

Sorry for the trouble I caused, I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also achieve the same with:

```
88,99s;\s\zs;easy-rsa/2.0/keys/;
```

Comment: base on you method I found that 88,99s;\s; easy-rsa/2.0/keys/; works too!